# ooxmlIsMalformated exception using insertFileFromBase64

Tags: ms-word, office-js

After inserting [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_life_sciences) into an Word Online document, I've tried to insert formatted `contentControl` in `base64` format.

When I attempted this, I received a `ooxmlIsMalformated` exception when calling the `insertFileFromBase64` method.

I've inserted the same `base64` string into empty document everything is ok.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you are new user, I recommend you read ["How to Ask a Good Question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Without sample code showing how you're encoding the document and calling the API there isn't a lot to go on here.

Comment: What does this mean: I've tried to insert formatted contentControl in base64 format?